# UIWebview rotation+transform issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

When a user presses a button i add a scale transform to make it zoom out like safari's tabbing. when user presses the webview it comes back up. When the view is rotated, i use to get the values of how i wanted the frame to look like in tab mode, and checked if it was in tab mode when rotating and applied the frame. it works, and ive tried taking it out. The issue is, if i rotate like 10 times, a black line on the right side gets bigger and bigger going inside the webview. i have logged tons of objects for the web view and its scrollview to see if anything is off, the scrollinset/offset is correct, the frame is correct, the transform is correct too. i cant figure out why theres the black line. i tried refreshing the webview to see if its the webpage, and it doesnt fix that ether,the scale transform values is

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.68)
```

for zoom out, and 1, 1 for zoom in. if anyone wants to see the effect just apply that to a uiwebview and start rotating the device about 10 times and you would then really see it.

heres how the web view looks when rotating a bunch of times: [image]

on the right side theres that thick black line, it gets bigger with every rotate but ONLY grows when that transform is added, if its normal size again it stops but stays there.

Comment: Have you read the documentation, namely [this one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html) ? you are scalling y-axis 0.68 times but x-axis - 0.6

Comment: Havnt read it, but I'm using the scale transform. So it makes it shrink out like safaris tabbing on iPhone. That's not the isse though, but it's we're the issue happens. After applying it, and rotating a bunch of times it makes this black line grow bigger and bigger from the right side towards the middle. Nothing so far can fix the issue

Comment: Firstly, post the code, where your app handles device rotations, so we could help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform any view, their frames do change, If you are using autoresize flag, check it since transforming changes frames and autoresizing also changes frames and this creates weird result.